# Angular JS- Calculate the sum of repeated elements using ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

I am newbie to Angular js. I am trying to calculate the sum of values of third column and save result into downtime box.
Here, I had already done.
1.Dynamically Add/remove the row.
2.Calculate the difference between the 1st column and 2nd column and save the result into third column.
3.Now,sum the values of third column and save into textbox.
Now, third point is not working.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="Myapp">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myctrl">

    <table id="t1" style="border:none;">
    <tr><th>Start</th><th>Stop</th><th>Downtime(In Min)</th><th>Reason</th></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in invoice">
    <td><input  type="text" required ng-model="$invoice.start" name="r1[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" required ng-model="$invoice.stop" ng-blur="diff($invoice)" name="r2[]"></td>
    <td><input  type="text" name="r3[]"  ng-model="$invoice.diff"/></td>
    <td><input  type="text" ng-model="$invoice.reason" name="r4[]" ></td>
    <td style="border:none;"><a href ng-click="remove(item)">X</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border:none;">
    <td style="border:none;"><a href ng-click="add()">+</a></td>
  </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <div> 
<span class="labelCode">Total Downtime</span><input required type="text" ng-value="run()" name="Tot_D" /></span></br>

</div>
```

Angular js

```
    var myapp=angular.module("Myapp",[]);
    myapp.controller("myctrl",function($scope){

     $scope.invoice =  [{
            start :"7:00",
            stop:"7:30" ,
            reason: "M/C Ready to Start",
               }]


                 $scope.add= function(){
                             $scope.invoice.push({
                             start:"7:30",
                             stop:"8:00"
                      });
                };
           //Remove the rows
                 $scope.remove=function(index){
                       $scope.invoice.splice(index,1);
                  };

                    $scope.diff = function(item) {
        item.diff = computeDiff(item.start,item.stop);
      }
  function computeDiff(start, stop) {
        if (start && stop) {
          var s_hr = start.split(":")[0];
          var s_min = start.split(":")[1];
          var e_hr = stop.split(":")[0];
          var e_min = stop.split(":")[1];

          return Math.abs((parseInt(e_hr) - parseInt(s_hr)) * 60) + Math.abs(parseInt(e_min) - parseInt(s_min))
        }
      }
                  $scope.run = function(){

      var total = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.invoice.length; i++){
            var product = $scope.invoice[i];
            total += parseInt($scope.diff());
        }
        return total; 
    }

    });
```

Sum of repeated values of third column is not updating into downtime text box.

I dont where I am going wrong.Please help me out.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest you to us `ng-init` directive for every iteration to calculate, but it's **Very Important** to use functions inside `ng-init`. Something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in invoice">
  <td><input type="text" ... ng-init="sum(item)"></td>
</tr>
```

Then inside your controller you can define that function and do there whatever you want, because `ng-repeat` ***will call*** that function for every iteration

Comment: I tried but its not working. I think there is wrong into function.It's not calculating anything.

Comment: honestly your code is not nice.I would change a lot of to get things better

Comment: Okay.I know.I am newbie, so it will take time to code neat and tidy.